# How to upload multiple files with AsyncHttpClient Android

Tags: android, post, multipart, android-async-http

I know I can upload single file from AsyncHttpClient

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

```
File myFile = new File("/path/to/file.png");
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
try {
    params.put("profile_picture", myFile);
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {}
```

But I have to upload multiple files to the server with multipart post.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a file array as value for the files key.
In order to do that, follow the code below:

```
File[] myFiles = { new File("pic.jpg"), new File("pic1.jpg") }; 
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
try {
    params.put("profile_picture[]", myFiles);
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

}
```

Aditionally, if you want a dynamic array, you can use an ArrayList
and convert to File[] type with the method .toArray()

```
ArrayList<File> fileArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

//...add File objects to fileArrayList

File[] files = new File[fileArrayList.size()];  
fileArrayList.toArray(files);
```

Hope this help. =D

Comment: I have a problem here: I do exactly as above, but then onSuccess CallBack does not get called. When I upload seven files [images] or so, I get only one image as whole and rest of them are blank. This works however with 4 files but, the call back for success never gets received.

Answer (score 1):

Create the SimpleMultipartEntity object and call the addPart for each file that you want to upload.

Comment: I want to add two files for the same key.. may be that is why this method is merging them

Comment: have you able to fix that? please share

Comment: No.. it wasn't my priority so just postponed the task.. if you find anything please reply to this thread with your answer. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 File[] files = lst.toArray(new File[lst.size()]);

    try {
        params.put("media[]", files);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass all your files as parameter on params. For example:

```
params.put("file_one", myFiles1);
params.put("file_two", myFiles2)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use this code:

```
public static void fileUpLoad(String url,File file,AsyncHttpResponseHandler asyncHttpResponseHandler){
    RequestParams requestParams=new RequestParams();

    try{
        requestParams.put("profile_picture", file,"application/octet-stream");
        client.post(url, requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The request is Multi-part uploading.